# Auto Complete searching with ignoring special character

Tags: jquery, mysql, autocomplete, laravel-8, typehead

I am working on auto-suggestion through jquery plugin typehead the issue is i have some words with special character if i not type with special character then the word is not appear in suggestion dropdown list

Like
**Cross-eye**
**crossed/eyes**

[image]

i want to search like that image i attach if any word have special characters then auto-suggestion show me result with that special character also even i am not type the special character in search area

My Code is

```
$('#search').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            source: function (query, process) {
                return $.get(url, {
                    q: query
                }, function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fuzzy search` for that. [Here](https://blog.pythian.com/fuzzy-search-sql-server-part-1/) you can see more details about `fuzzy search`.

Comment: please provide me solution in auto complete or typehead